# Can't get Ctrl+A to register in PuTTY?

Tags: linux, debian, gnu-screen, putty

I'm trying to use Screen on a remote server. Everyone else can use Ctrl+A so I know it's set up correctly in the .screenrc, but for some reason I think my PuTTY client is setup wrong.

Under terminal > keyboard I have selected ESC[n~, I also tried vt100+ and still no dice. Under connection > data I tried changing terminal-type to vt100.

When I try to use Ctrl+a ? for example, it's as if I didn't press Ctrl+a at all. It just puts a ? into the shell. If I do Ctrl+d it closes screen like it should.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `^A` is used by `screen`, see `^A?`. To send a single `^A`, use two: `^A^A`. Read `man screen`.

Comment: @waltinator if I do ^A? nothing happens. That's the issue I'm having.